# how to iterate dictionary by for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
requestArr= {
    'test1': {
        "id_comments": "ABC",
        "id_testname": "abc",
    },
    'test2' : {
        "id_comments": "DEF",
        "id_testname": "def",
    },
    'test3' : {
        "id_comments": "GHI",
        "id_testname": "ghi",
    }
}
```

How to Add this in python "For loop" one by one with values as e.g.

```
test1{id_comments & id_testname}
# and so on
```

e.g.-

```
for i in requestArr:
    for j in requestArr[i]:
        for k in requestArr[i][j]:
            print k['id_comments']
            print k['id_testname']
            # query to database
```

getting error

> indices must be integers, not str

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain again what you want? I don't understand. You want to define the values or read them ?

Comment: `for elem in requestArr.values(): print elem`

Comment: Thanks CoryKramer for editing with proper fonts. tglaria kindly see the question now.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the dictionaries `items`

```
for key, value in requestArr.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Output

```
test2 {'id_comments': 'DEF', 'id_testname': 'def'}
test1 {'id_comments': 'ABC', 'id_testname': 'abc'}
test3 {'id_comments': 'GHI', 'id_testname': 'ghi'}
```

Comment: Will work, but this is python3. Also should use `viewitems()`

Comment: @cricket_007 This will work in both Python 3.x and Python 2.7. And in this case it is not important if they use `items` or `viewitems`

Comment: Hi @Corykramer, I want to achieve this -                                                   for i in requestArr:
    for j in requestArr[i]:
        for k in requestArr[i][j]:
            print k['id_comments']
            print k['id_testname']
            # query to database

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2.7**

`items()` will return list of tuple.

```
>>> requestArr.items()
[('test1', {'id_comments': 'ABC', 'id_testname': 'abc'}), ('test3', {'id_comments': 'GHI', 'id_testname': 'ghi'}), ('test2', {'id_comments': 'DEF', 'id_testname': 'def'})]
```

`iteritems()` will return itemiterator object.

```
>>> requestArr.iteritems()
<dictionary-itemiterator object at 0xb6d3b734>
>>> for k, v in requestArr.iteritems():
...    print k, v
... 
test1 {'id_comments': 'ABC', 'id_testname': 'abc'}
test3 {'id_comments': 'GHI', 'id_testname': 'ghi'}
test2 {'id_comments': 'DEF', 'id_testname': 'def'}
>>>
```

**Python 3.x**

One of Python 3’s changes is that items() now return iterators, and a list is never fully built. The iteritems() method is also gone, since items() now works like iteritems() in Python 2.